# using php to create an xml file from a mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, xml

im trying to create a xml file using php.everytime i run the code the page displayes the code from a certain point as text on the screen.the code i hav is as follows:

```
<?php
    if(!$dbconnet = mysql_connect('I took out the details')){
        echo "connection failed to the host.";
        exit;
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db('siamsati_db')){
        echo "Cannot connect to the database.";
        exit;
    }
    $table_id = 'events';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_id";
    $dbresult = mysql_query($query, $dbconnect);

    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');

    $root = $doc->createElement('root');
    $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult)){
        $ooc = $doc->createElement($table_id);
        $occ = $root->appendChild($occ);

        foreach ( $row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue){

            $child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
            $child = $occ->appendchild($child);

            $value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
            $value = $child->appendChild($value);
        }
    }

    $xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
    echo $xml_string;

?>
```

and the page when displayed shows:

> createElement('root'); $root =
>   $doc->appendChild($root); while($row =
>   mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult)){ $ooc =
>   $doc->createElement($table_id); $occ =
>   $root->appendChild($occ); foreach (
>   $row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue){
>   $child =
>   $doc->createElement($fieldname);
>   $child = $occ->appendchild($child);
>   $value =
>   $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
>   $value = $child->appendChild($value);
>   } } $xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
>   echo $xml_string; ?>

is there something ive missed.ive checked all the quotes thinking it was that at first but they all seem to be right.any suggestions on what im doing wrong are much appreciated?

Comment: What happens if you execute a page containing this: 
    <?php echo "hello world"; ?> ?

Comment: Is there a `?` before the `>` in the line that reads `$root = $doc->createElement('root');`? That would make the PHP interpreter switch to HTML mode and dump everything that follows giving the output you posted. At least I cannot imagine you compiled PHP with `->` as the closing tag. That'd be totally sick.

Comment: rik your remark is likely to be the problem, I can't think of any other possibility.

Comment: The code above is exactly the same code as i hav except i left out the closing tag at the end in the code above.theres no ? before the > in the line $root = $doc->createElement('root');

Comment: coud you var_dump($row); and see what output?

Comment: Generate XML File Using PHP And MySQL - http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/03/generate-xml-file-using-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the content type to be XML, so that the browser will   recognise it as XML.

```
header( "content-type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-15" );
```

In your code Change it to:

```
// Set the content type to be XML, so that the browser will   recognise it as XML.
header( "content-type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-15" );

// "Create" the document.
$doc = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );
```

+++I think you can do something like this

```
<root>
<?
   foreach ( $row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue){
    ?>
    <events>
        <fieldname><?=fieldname; ?></fieldname>
        <fieldvalue><?=$fieldvalue; ?></fieldvalue>
    </events>
    }
?>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've posted here the initial `<?php` tag is missing...